# How can I draw lines on big images using gesture recognizer without memory issues

Tags: ios, ipad, drawing, core-graphics, cgcontext

I am working on an app, and at some point the user needs to draw something over an image.
The code i wrote works just fine for images around `1500x1500` and smaller, but once the images get bigger, the problem starts.

When images get too big, it takes more time to do the drawing, and the Gesture Recognizer gets called rarely.

Here's how I did it: there are two classes, one is a `UIScrollView` subclass called `DrawView` and one is a `UIImageView` subclass called `MyPen`. `DrawView` has a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` that sends messages to `MyPen` every time it gets recognized (I get the `[recognizer state]` and depending on it i start or move a line). `DrawView` has two UIImageView objects in its subviews, one for the background image, and one for the drawings (the pen).

here's what I do in MyPen:

```
- (void)beginLine:(CGPoint) currentPoint
{
    previousPoint = currentPoint;
}

- (void)moveLine:(CGPoint) currentPoint
{
    self.image = [self drawLineFromPoint:previousPoint toPoint:currentPoint image:self.image];
    previousPoint = currentPoint;
}

- (UIImage *)drawLineFromPoint:(CGPoint)fromPoint toPoint:(CGPoint)toPoint image:(UIImage *)image
{
CGSize screenSize = self.frame.size;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(screenSize);
CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenSize.width, screenSize.height)];

CGContextSetLineCap(currentContext, kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetLineWidth(currentContext, _thickness);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(currentContext, _color);
CGContextBeginPath(currentContext);
CGContextMoveToPoint(currentContext, fromPoint.x, fromPoint.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(currentContext, toPoint.x, toPoint.y);
CGContextStrokePath(currentContext);

UIImage *ret = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return ret;
}
```

When the image is big enough, it takes some time for CoreGraphics to render it, and so the gesture recognizer doesn't get recognized so often, and sends less points to the pen.

The question here is: Is there a way to optimize the drawing? Should I use another Thread for ir ? Is there another way around it ?
Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should split foreground (the lines) and the background (the image the lines should be drawn on) into two Views. So you can only update the foreground View every time the user moves his finger. You can compose the two views into one Image when the user finishs drawing.

Drawing an image inside a CGContext is very expensive, especialy when large.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, that's exactly what I'm doing. But it still takes some time to do the drawing. I tried to just add the points to an array, and draw once he removes the finger from the screen. It works, but the user doesn't see what he's drawing

Comment: in your `- (UIImage *)drawLineFromPoint:(CGPoint)fromPoint toPoint:(CGPoint)toPoint image:(UIImage *)image` you are drawing the image befor you are drawing the path. Is the image representing the old sub-paths? If so, i suggest to save the lines in multiple subpaths rather than in an image. You can draw all paths everytime the user moves it finger. One he removes the finger you can compose an Image, clear all sub-paths, and start over.

Comment: you nailed it ! Thank you very much !